# How many integers are there less than n with at least k odd integer?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, inclusion-exclusion

Question :
How many integers are there  $\leqslant n$  with at least k odd integer in digits?

I having a problem using the inclusion-exclusion principle here. How to solve it without the inclusion-exclusion principle?But solution with inclusion-exclusion is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: For learning other method , which can help me future. You can give me the solution with inclusion-exclusion  principle , it is appreciated.

Comment: I'm looking at the Online Math Olympiad 2013 Winter at http://internetolympiad.org/archive/OMOWinter13/OMOWinter13Probs.pdf and I'm not seeing this problem.

Comment: i think it will be omo-12 in question 4 but it was very easy, it asks for finding all even numbers with an at least one even digit? I said such type, I want to find how to solve How many integers are there ⩽n with at least k odd integer in digits? for the type of question.

Comment: I am editing the question

Comment: OK, it's at http://internetolympiad.org/archive/OMOWinter12/OMOWinter12Solns.pdf "How many positive even numbers have an even number of digits and are less than 10000?" So it's a very different kind of question; nothing about the number of even digits, just that the last digit has to be even, and the number of digits has to be even. The more general question that you ask probably gets very messy to answer when $n$ isn't a power of ten, when $n$ is much bigger than $10000$, and when, say, at most half the digits are allowed to be odd.